# Why doesn't my $location.path('test') change the address bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.location

I'm working in a huge code base, so I can't duplicate results in a fiddle. The component I'm working on is written in Angular.

So far I've tried

```
window.location.href = 'test'
$location.path('test')
$location.hash('test')
```

Each variation works, and the console.log confirms that the hash has changed, however my address bar remains the same.

I understand there are many variables that could be causing this, but I'm out of avenues to explore. Could anyone give me some possible causes that I might be overlooking? I've scoured the code base for preventDefault(), I've tried every different way of setting the hash imaginable, I even tried wrapping the hash redefinition in a setTimeout.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code could be in a frame... See if doing `var t=window;while(parent!=t)t=parent;t.location.href='test';`

Comment: How about `$location.path('/test')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
$timeout(function() {    
     $location.path('test');
});
```

Take present that all the angular actions must be run on the digest cycle of the app. If you are making this call using a function that is not handle it using some of the angular services, the context is not notified of the change.

Comment: Thank you! It was this and using $scope.apply() once it was set